# Tableau add filter inside calculated field

Tags: data-visualization, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop

In Tableau i have a calculated field like this below:

```
COUNTD( 
IF(
MONTH([Dataevent]) == 4
) THEN [Id] end)
/
COUNTD( 
IF(
YEAR([Dataevento]) == 2018
) THEN [Id] end)
```

i would like to add a filter to automatically select from the sheet the month and the year without hardcoding them, like this:

```
COUNTD( 
IF(
MONTH([Dataevent]) == filter
) THEN [Id] end)
/
COUNTD( 
IF(
YEAR([Dataevento]) == filter
) THEN [Id] end)
```

how should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [parameters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_create.htm).

You have to

1. create a parameter
2. use it inside your calculated field
3. Add a filter control to the parameter

You can find a good tutorial following [this link](https://www.coenterprise.com/blog/using-parameters-within-calculated-fields-in-tableau/).